# Using with statement on cursor in cx_Oracle

Tags: python, with-statement, cx-oracle

cx_Oracle contains `__enter__` and `__exit__` on Connection objects, but not on Cursor objects. Thus, I use this everywhere to wrap cursors :

```
class CursorWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, connection):
        self.connection = connection
        self.cursor = None

    def __enter__(self):
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        return self.cursor

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
       self.cursor.close()
```

then, when I want a cursor

```
with CursorWrapper(cnx) as cursor:
    cursor.execute("whatever sql statement")
```

It suits my needs fairly well.

However, I was then wondering what could prevent `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods to be added directly in cx_Oracle ?

Or is there a better way to use cursors with context managements, which would explain why it is not defined in the module ?

Answer (score 0):

[Solution moved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309552/997587) from [@MathieuC.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3146720/mathieu-c)'s question post.

> I can just use contextlib.closing.
>
> ```
> import contextlib
> with contextlib.closing(cnx.cursor()) as cursor:
> ```